# freeze top row and first two columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and am trying to achieve the following:
1. Top row should be frozen while scrolling vertically.
2. First two columns should be frozen wile scrolling horizontally.

I applied the column.Freeze = true and its working fine, but when applying row[0].freeze = true, it doesn't work for row freezing.

Comment: `row[0].freeze = true` implies freezing a cell, no?

Comment: I guess he meant rows[0].freeze. I don't think row[0].freeze would compile..

Comment: `.Rows[0].Frozen = true;` should work ! !

Comment: Here is an example of how you could do it, test to see if it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I create the DataGridView, I associate it with a DataTable and then immediately set the first two rows to freeze. The rows don't freeze. However, if I handle a button click and set the rows to freeze in that button click, the rows successfully freeze. How, then, do I freeze the rows immediately upon associating the table?

Here's some code:

```
 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    // Just add a bunch of columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Col" + i.ToString(), typeof
    (string));
    }

    // Add a bunch of rows to the DataTable, with some dummy
    values
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
    row["Col" + j.ToString()] = "Val" + i.ToString() +
    "-" + j.ToString();
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    gridView.DataSource = dataTable;

    gridView.Rows[1].Frozen = true;
```

This won't work. The rows are not frozen. However if I stick the `gridView.Rows[1].Frozen = true;` line in a button event handler, it works. How would I do this, then, without requiring an event trigger from the user? I see two solutions:

1. Bind the data this way:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   c.Name = "Col" + i.ToString();
   gridView.Columns.Add(c);
   }
   gridView.Rows.Add(100);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
   gridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = "Val" + i.ToString() + "-" + j.ToString();
   gridView.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
   ```
2. Select frozen rows in this event:

   ```
   private void gridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
   DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
   {
   FrozeFirstRow();
   }
   ```

Comment: freezing (dataGridViewPlatypi.Rows[0].Frozen = true;) did not work for me.

Comment: I did reproduce this problem, which occured on my site only inside the constructor. I solved this using the VisibleChanged-Event: grivView.VisibleChanged += (s, e) => { FrozeFirstRow(); };