# Prevent first n rows being scrolled

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

How do I prevent scrolling of first 3 rows of a  datagridView being scrolled away.

Application is C# windows Forms with net framework 4.5

Comment: Something along the lines "mygrid.rows(2).frozen = true" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Arvo, it does'nt work.. I had already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property [`DataGridViewRow.Frozen Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx)  should work with Scrolling with a `DataGridView`, The **only thing to do is to set it up in [`DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event: like:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count >= 3)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Frozen = true;
    }
}
```

You can set the `Rows[2]` to frozen as the above rows from that position will freeze as well.

From [DataGridViewRow.Frozen Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This property lets you keep one or several rows of important
>   information in place when a user scrolls through the DataGridView.
>   **All rows above the frozen row are also frozen.**

Add the event to your Grid like:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
```

and then the data binding like:

```
DataTable dt = GetDataFromDB();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Thanks, as suggested it works only if set on DataBindingComplete event.

Comment: @TonyP, Just realized one more thing, You don't have to loop through the rows and set all top three to frozen, instead you can just set the third row to Frozen and the rows above it will freeze as well.

Answer (score 0):

See a similar question answered on StackOverflow: [freeze top row and first two columns in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876951/freeze-top-row-and-first-two-columns-in-datagridview)

What you are looking for is the DataGridViewRow.Frozen property.
It allows you to freeze any rows you wish. (preventing them from being scrolled)

You can use it like this:

```
dataGridView.Rows[0].Frozen = true;
```

This is well documented in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.frozen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you have any problems doing this, please add the code to your question.